# Video sharing wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, social-networking

I am new to WordPress development and I am in need to develop a WordPress website where users can registered and share videos and images, I searched a lot to find any suitable theme that allows users to do this stuff, 
So please let me know if there exists such theme that can help me or Do I need to code it myself.

This may be not a very useful question to discuss here but I have searched a lot and wasted my lot of time to find best option to achieve this in  minimum time.

Hope to find good help here.

Thanks
Zauk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no off-the-shelf theme I've seen that can do this, and I'm sure there are a bunch of plugins that can help. If, like me, you'd prefer to actually know your code, I've created a "toolkit" to help folks spin up web apps like what you've described using WordPress: https://github.com/cferdinandi/web-app-starter-kit/

WordPress for Web Apps includes functions to handle user registration, password changes, logged-in vs. logged-out content and more. This won't get you all the way there, but it's a start.

The image/video sharing piece gets a bit harder. Are you looking for folks to upload images and videos, or just share URLs from around the web? Either way, you should look into the `update_user_meta` hook as a way to save content and uniquely associate it with the user. You can use form inputs on the front-end, and save the content through the backend. I know I'm not giving you a "here's the code you need" answer, but because this sounds like a custom project to me, I hope I've at least got you looking in the right direction.